# Stop Dreamweaver converting find replace queries when loaded via dreamweaver.setUpComplexFindReplace

Tags: replace, dreamweaver, html-encode

I want a find/replace that matches the HTML encoded tab character `&#9;` and replace it with a space.

When I load the following query via Dreamweaver's `dreamweaver.setUpComplexFindReplace` API function, the `&#9;` is converted to a literal tab character, so no matches are made.

How do I stop the HTML encoded string from being converted?

```
dreamweaver.setUpComplexFindReplace('<dwquery>  <queryparams matchcase="false" ignorewhitespace="false" useregexp="false" wholeword="true" />  <find searchmode="document">    <qtext qname="&#9;" qraw="true"></qtext>  </find>  <replace action="replaceText" param1="" param2=""/></dwquery>');
dreamweaver.replaceAll();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `qtext` node, change the `qname` value from `&#9;` to `&amp;#9`.

Comment: I added a semicolon at the end of the query text, making it `&amp;#9;` to match all the encode tab. Your answer worked great, much appreciated.